# Flex Cyrillic localization

Tags: apache-flex, localization, flex3

I've defined a Russian localization file but when setting the locale all I get is ? symbols... 
When creating a sample flex app with Cyrillic characters they are displayed just fine, but somehow setting the locale does no work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it...
My localization files were not encoded in UTF8, that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using embedded fonts, but the characters you're trying to display aren't included in the font.

From the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_07.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- fonts/EmbeddedFontCharacterRange.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Style>
  @font-face {
    src:url("../assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
    unicodeRange:
       U+0041-U+005A, /* Upper-Case [A..Z] */
       U+0061-U+007A, /* Lower-Case a-z */
       U+0030-U+0039, /* Numbers [0..9] */
       U+002E-U+002E; /* Period [.] */
 }

 TextArea {
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    fontSize: 32;
 }
```

Comment: Actually i'm not using embedded fonts... Like I said previously when switching the locate to Russian all the localized characters switch to '?', setting it back to English works just fine